# Get specific element in Mongo DB $group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm testing with Mongo 2.6 and the zips sample data and I'd like to be able to get either latitude or longitude whilst querying and uses the aggregate framework, here is an example I've cobbled together:

```
db.zips.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    city: 1,
    loc: 1
  }
}, {
  $unwind: '$loc'
}, {
  $group: {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "city": {
      $first: "$city"
    },
    "lat": {
      $first: "$loc"
    }
  }
}])
```

`$slice` does exactly what I want instead of $unwind and $group because I just want to extract a specific field from an array, but you can't use it in the aggregation framework from what I can tell.

So `$unwind` seems to do similar when I group, the problem is `$first` is great at picking up the first element, and technically as its a 2 element block I could use `$last`, but if it was > 2 elements, how would I tell it that I want the `2nd` element?

===Edit===

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4589

I found this which is along the lines of what I am after and clearly broken still, so I think I'm hitting a dead end. Still open to suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want this in an aggregate function but im not sure it's possible. You can do this in a MapReduce function instead. It gives you a lot more flexibility working with the data.

Here is a query that selects the fields as you seem to be after in your example:

```js
db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "zips",
  "map" : function() {
    emit(this._id, {
      city: this.city, 
      lat: this.loc[0], // First array elem
      long: this.loc[1] // Second array elem
    });
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, values) { return values[0]; }, 
  "out": { inline: 1 }
});
```

I don't do any actual reducing here as you don't do it in your question. You could edit the reduce function if needed.